How to pass a dictionary through to a template in Django?
I am watching a Django tutorial (Corey Schafer on how to build a webapp, however I had to use a different method of getting the template to appear. That is all working well. The function he uses has an argument where I don't, that allows the dictionary to appear on the site. Any ideas on how to fix this? (sorry if this is a rookie question, I'm very new)
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def home(request):
    context = {
        'news': news
    }
    template = loader.get_template('home.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render())

I tried to pass it through alongside template.render(), and it made all of the raw HTML code come up on screen.

who is Corey Schafer ? If you watch tutorial then you could add link in question (not in comment).

Just a youtube, didnt know that was something I could do, thanks for letting me know.

When using django.shortcuts.render (as opposed to template.render) one should not use HttpResponse directly.
Instead, pass in the request object, the template path/name, the context dict and the HTTP status.
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    context = {
        'news': news
    }

    return render(request, 'home.html', context=context, status=200)

HttpResponse has no idea what a context dict is and how to apply it to a template, its single job is to accept a string and return it to the client.

Thanks very much, works perfectly!!!!! Had to use template.render to navigate using render() but turns out I didnt have to!

@Ben if this solved your question, consider marking as complete.
